# Parallel-series RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

I wanted to calculate frequencies of filter

[image]

The module of impedance which I got is equal

[image]

What is the frequency cutoff of this circuit?

I've made a [simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmaBmA7MgHMh2wBOZZSBMBANhAUhproQFMBaMMAKAHdxiVJsvZOAzVIHAMZCR1HILCioIACzQM8DZrjLWgloWjKwyyoTDJl2XGDTIMrY1FiROPIsNLy+FuuIBO0j4oVijKvuDw3MHyinL8guI8cUHJAlBRqYJokMrx6VLZuZ4gaJSCxb7OcBAsMPBmxsRURlQuaLl1LhwBpeVpypZ5dGCRAPIqg8WWdBXpCsPeacZFacPwoYSb0Js7u5vUSDCcAPYghCCUHSqQhPKVEMMcQA) but I wanted to get frequency cutoff.

Comment: It has no load so there is also no current flowing in any part of the circuit so no voltage drops either. So by itself it does nothing, output voltage is always equal to input voltage and thus the cutoff frequency is infinite as it does not exist.

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, then ask a specific question. If it is **not** homework then just run a simulation.

Comment: It's not a homework. I added simulation. I'm looking for specific formula like for example $$\omega = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

Comment: The cutoff frequency is defined as the point where the output is -3dB of the input amplitude. To have a cutoff frequency, you need to define where the input and output are in the circuit. If you define the left and right node as input/output then it still isnt doing any filtering, you need a ground too

Comment: @Miron Just because it's common to see that convention it doesn't mean that it applies to all. Therefore you can't say "it is defined", since there's nothing stopping the user to define it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive transfer functions require an impedance ratio just as 2 resistors provide in series-shunt.

Here's an example with your 2 reactive parts creating 3 break points and -6dB above them all.

[image]

Use this as an example to check your homework. (20 dB /decade showing last break point at -9 dB.)  This will also test your skills at reading log plots..